# SQL error while creating a new table, what am I missing

Tags: sql

```sql
create table paydetails ( 
  emp_id integer (20),
  dept_id integer (20),
  basic integer(20),
  deductions integer(20),
  additions integer (20),
  joining_date date(20,20,20)
);
```

Comment: Be mindful of the tags you use when asking a question. html and css are irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in almost any database:

```
create table paydetails (
    emp_id int,
    dept_id int,
    basic int,
    deductions int,
    additions int,
    joining_date date
);
```

Most databases do not have a parameter for `int` (although some interpret that as a length).

As far as I know, none have three parameters for `date`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Do yourself the favor of adding in the auto increment `id` as your unique/primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE `db_name`.`paydetails` ( 
`id` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`emp_id` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
`dept_id` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
`basic` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
`deductions` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
`additions` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
`joining_date` DATE NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```